# Java Regular expression validation

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to validate a string which allows only alpha numeric values and only 
    one dot character and  only underscore character in java .

```
String fileName = (String) request.getParameter("read");
```

I need to validate the fileName retrieving from the request and should 
satisfy  the above criteria

I tried in `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_'.']*$"`  , but this allows more than one dot character

I need to validate my string in the given scenarios ,

1 . Filename contains only alpha numeric values .
   2 . It allows only one dot character (.) ,  example : fileRead.pdf , 
       fileWrite.txt etc
   3 . it allows only underscore characters . All the other symbols should be 
       declined

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: can you share an input output example please?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ this online service lets you try out regex and explains the single characters and what they do in a regex really nice. It's very good for self study :)

Comment: you should point whether the filename contains file extension. your pattern  allows last dot and first dot.

Comment: You do realize that both Windows and Unix/Linux/OSX allow filenames with more than one dot character? Is there a specific purpose for your special restriction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use **String.matches()** method :

```
System.out.println("My_File_Name.txt".matches("\\w+\\.\\w+"));
```

You can also use **java.util.regex** package.

```
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = 
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.\\w+");

java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("My_File_Name.txt");

System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

For more information about **REGEX and JAVA**, look at this page : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Don't use `matcher.find()` but `matcher.matches()`. The regex part of your answer accepts input like `ßαd.txt` (or worse: `.........a.txt`). If you use `matches()`, that won't be the case anymore.

Comment: you must escape backslash double.

Comment: Thanks you Olivier

Comment: Thanks you mattn :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use two negative lookaheads here:

```
^((?!.*\..*\.)(?!.*_.*_)[A-Za-z0-9_.])*$
```

Each lookahead asserts that either a dot or an underscore does *not* occur two times, implying that it can occur at most once.

It wasn't completely clear whether you *require* one dot and/or underscore.  I assumed not, but my regex could be easily modified to this requirement.

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can first check the special characters which have the number limits.
Here is the code:

```
int occurance = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf("123123..32131.3", ".");
```

or

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("123123..32131.3", ".");
```

If it does not match your request you can discard it before regex check.
If there is no problem you can now put your String to alphanumeric value check.